# logic apps designer can't select Twilio - Get Message

Tags: azure, twilio, azure-logic-apps

I am a total newbie to Azure Logic Apps and Twilio.
I am trying to follow the instructions [to create a connection to Twilio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-twilio#create-a-connection-to-twilio).

However I can't click the any of the Twilio icons:

[image: any of the Twilio icons]

I am logged into Twilio on another browser tab.

I have tried Edge and Chrome.

If I press F12, I can see there are numerous errors in the console tab:

[image: like this]

How do I go about troubleshooting my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to put Twilio actions as first step of your Logic App.

Twilio connector hasn't triggers, then you need as the first step of your Logic App a trigger, as a HTTP Request and then add a Twilio action:

[image: Logic App with Twilio action]

Then you need to fill the Twilio action with the **Account Id** and the **Access Token** provided by Twilio. The **Connection Name** is whatever you want.

Comment: so are the steps in the Microsoft instructions I link to wrong?

Comment: Well, that link explain how to use the Twilio connector, not create a Logic App. In the intro there is a comment with a link for that "Get started by creating a logic app; see Create a logic app."

Comment: Thank you. The instructions don't seem to mention adding the trigger

Comment: Are the Account Id and the Account SID the same thing?

Comment: You've to fill the Account ID field of the Logic App connector with the Account SID of the Twilio Dasboard (hexadecimal characters like ACaece5682365...)